# Ember.js: How can I prevent a user from exiting a dirty dialog?

Tags: ember.js

When a user has unsaved changes in a dialog, I would like to warn him before he can transition somewhere else.

This check should happen, when he either clicks on a link or changes the hash manually.

Is there a way in ember to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to stop transitions in Ember.  On the bright side, this issue is [currently being addressed on github](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1786).

You can wait for it be solved, or help out if you'd like.

Meanwhile, you can use manual actions instead of the `linkTo` helper that check if there are uncommitted changes.

In your template:

```
<a {{action goHome}}>Home</a>
```

In your route:

```
events: {
  goHome: function() {
    var isCommitted = !this.controllerFor('post').get('isDirty');
    if (isCommitted || confirm('You will lose your changes')) {
      this.transitionTo('home');
    }
  }
}
```

The downside is, you will lose the URLs in your links, which means the user won't be able to open links in a new tab.